# Can't convert markdown into HTML using StackExchanges's PageDown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I have a method of storing straight markup code (generate by PageDown's editor) into a database. On another page, I grab the markup from the database and run it through the markdown converter, however I can't seem to get any output. This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var converter = Markdown.Converter();
        $("#description-content").text(converter.makeHTML("<?php echo $description ?>"));
    });
</script>
```

PHP is echoing the pure markdown text from the database. When I visit the page, there isn't anything that shows up in the div. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm not seeing any echo'ed text and if I simple add plaintext inside the `.text()`, I can see it.

Comment: What does `$description` contain? Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: `$description` contains pure markdown source. Currently it contains: `**this is bold**`

Comment: If I just put plain text inside the `.text()` part it works.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP but i believe you can't use PHP inside javascript, since PHP is serverside and won't run in the users browser.

Comment: @AndresIlich, seeing as I'm echoing with PHP on the server side, the content of `$description` gets placed inside the jQuery when it reaches the browser.

Comment: How about JavaScript errors? Were you getting any with the echo'd text?

Comment: Came here looking for a different reason... And even though this is 3 years later, I want to comment for the sake of the issue. If you are able to see the result when you use regular text, but not a PHP echo, the issue is with the echo. Maybe a C&P fail, but you are missing a `;` after `$description` which would certainly stop the echo.

Comment: poor approach here `...(converter.makeHTML("<?php echo $description ?>"));` since it wont be able to understand complex posts that are mixed with codes and characters. check my soln for better approach in php

Answer (score 4):

`Markdown.Converter` is a constructor; you have to use

```
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
```

Answer (score 1):

A late answer but it might help new visitors

If you are fetchig result from database and echo through PHP i would prefer https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/classic/

Once you download the file, One can use it to convert the markdown text to html.

```
<?php 

$query_post = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `posts` ...//your query
$row_post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_post);

$content = $row_post['Body'];
include("path-to/PHP-Markdown-Extra-1.2.8/markdown.php");
$text = <<<EOD

$content

EOD;
echo Markdown($text);
?>
```

This will display result like my answer here, or any other answer or question here in stackoverflow

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using `Showdown` instead of `PageDown` and see if you get any different results, just as a test: https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/blob/master/src/showdown.js `Showdown` is another Markdown js implementation.

The code you have there doesn't look to have anything wrong with it, the only edge case I can think of would be unescaped quotation marks in `$description`.